# cannot get a variable from a prompt as a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt

On `button` right click I need:
- hide the button
- **then** show a prompt
- write the prompt value
- get the value in console

```js
function a_ren(){
 var a = 'lorem';
 $('.cmenu').hide(function(){var res = prompt('RENAME', a);});
 console.log(res);
}

$(document).on('contextmenu', 'button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    a_ren();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='cmenu'>CLICK</button>
```

Two problems:
- console error - `res` is not defined
- here on `SO` the prompt window appears but on my page (`chrome`, `localhost`) the prompt window doesn't appear at all.

Any help?

Comment: Well written question ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res` is undefined because you declare it inside the `hide` function and try to print it outside of the it(not in the scope). Put the console log inside the function and it should solve it.

```js
function a_ren(){
 var a = 'lorem';
 $('.cmenu').hide(function(){
    var res = prompt('RENAME', a);
    console.log(res);
  });
}

$(document).on('contextmenu', 'button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    a_ren();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='cmenu'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the scope of `var res` is inside the hide complete callback, also even if you declare res outside the function you will not get the value from prompt as the hide complete callback is asynchronous, so you have to process the prompt result inside the callback itself, refer the following code

```js
function a_ren() {
 var a = 'lorem';
 $('.cmenu').hide(function () {
  var res = prompt('RENAME', a);
  process_prompt_result(res);
        // scope of res ends here, its undefined outside this function
 });
}

$(document).on('contextmenu', 'button', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 a_ren();
});

function process_prompt_result(result) {
 // do something thing with result value from prompt
 console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='cmenu'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `res` is not defined is because the function passed to `hide()` doesn't run until after the hide animation finishes but `console.log(res);` is called without waiting. Also, as Ram Segev pointed out, `res` is defined within the `hide` callback function so thats the only place its in scope (accessible).

As for the prompt not appearing, try changing

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', 'button', function(e){
```

to

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
```